# JBoss java.io.IOException during deployment

Tags: jboss, manifest, jboss7.x, ioexception

I am building a JBoss Application Server module, on JBossAS 7.1.1. While trying to modify the classpath in the manifest file, I ran into this error:

```
12:30:53,097 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "MyDeployableProject.war"
12:30:53,141 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."MyDeployableProject.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MyDeployableProject.war".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "MyDeployableProject.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Failed to get manifest for deployment "/opt/server/bin/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/MyDeployableProject.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.deploy(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:73) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid header field
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:393) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:182) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:52) [classes.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.readManifest(VFSUtils.java:216)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.getManifest(VFSUtils.java:199)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.deploy(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:69) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out, a slight bug in `MANIFEST.MF` was causing this issue. The file was:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path:
```

Turns out, the bug was due to there being no space after `Class-Path:`. This (only a space different) is what works:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path:
```

Hopefully this will stop others from wondering.

Answer (score 7):

Also, you could have something as:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: org.slf4j,org.apache.commons.logging
**,org.joda.time**
Built-By: Pablo
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_30
Created-By: Apache Maven
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

instead of

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: org.slf4j,org.apache.commons.logging,org.joda.time
Built-By: Pablo
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_30
Created-By: Apache Maven
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

In this case, review pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
<!-- IMPORTANT: All dependencies in te same line -->                            <Dependencies>org.slf4j,org.apache.commons.logging,org.joda.time</Dependencies>
                        </manifestEntries>

                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Check the format of both the Manifest.MF file in code *and* the actual deployed file in the deployment folder for this sort of error.  I spent a good 20 mins or so trying all sort of nonsense in the file in my code base, only to find that it was the deployed Manifest.MF file that was the issue instead.